# JavaFx TreeView with CheckBox and ContextMenu

Tags: checkbox, javafx, treeview, contextmenu

in the tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tree-view.htm it explain how to create a TreeView with ContextMenu or CheckBox.

but is it possible to have both of them?

when I first copy-paste the code, I learned that I can have only one setCellFactory since they overwrite each other.

```
    // the following two setCellFactory are copied from the tutorial

    // this create TreeCell with ContextMenu
    treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>,TreeCell<String>>(){
        @Override
        public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> p) {
            return new TextFieldTreeCellImpl();
            //the class TextFieldTreeCellImp is a TreeCell with ContextMenu
        }
    });

    // this create TreeCell with CheckBox
    tree.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.<String>forTreeView());
```

then i tried substituting TreeCell with CheckBoxTreeCell

```
    //class TextFieldTreeCellImpl extends TreeCell<String> {
    class TextFieldTreeCellImpl extends CheckBoxTreeCell<String> {
    ...
    //TreeItem newTag = new TreeItem<String>("New tag");
    CheckBoxTreeItem newTag = new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("New tag");
```

but the checkbox didn't appear. it's still a normal treeview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the fastest way to get a `TreeView` with `CheckBoxes` and a `ContextMenu` is adding the `ContextMenu` within the factory callback:

```
treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>,TreeCell<String>>() {

  @Override
  public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> param) {
    TreeCell<String> cell = CheckBoxTreeCell.<String>forTreeView().call(param);
    ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
    MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem("Item 1");
    MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("Item 2");

    EventHandler<ActionEvent> eh = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

      @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
          System.out.println("Item '" + event.getSource() + 
            "' of cell '" + cell + "' was clicked.");
      }
    };

    item1.setOnAction(eh);
    item2.setOnAction(eh);
    menu.getItems().add(item1);
    menu.getItems().add(item2);
    cell.setContextMenu(menu);
    return cell;
  }
});
```

I call the usual `TreeCell` factory for the `CheckBoxes`. However, before returning the cell I add the `ContextMenu`.

Using the `EventHandler`, you can specify the clicking behaviour of the respective item.

If you have further questions or this is not a satisfying solution of you problem, feel free to contact me.

Comment: it works!!! the TreeCell has both, CheckBox and ContextMenu. but I remember that event.getSource() would return a MenuItem, and not a TreeCell. that's an other topic thought.

Comment: Yes it would. However, of course you can reference `cell` within the `EventHandler`. I updated the example accordingly.